# How to replace missing icons with another icon-pack?

Tags: icons, icon-themes

Is there a way to replace missing icons with icons in another pack we prefer instead of Hi-Color that Ubuntu uses by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the icon to `~/.icons` using the same name used in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/...`. The point is that applications look first on `~/.icons` for the icons they need.

For example, the icon for Nautilus is `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/nautilus.svg`. If you want to override it, add the icon you want to `/home/username/.icons` with the name `nautilus.svg` (must be a `.svg` image in this case).

If `~/.icons` does not exists you need to create it

```
cd && mkdir .icons
```

Notice that, in general, you should use the same folder structure used in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor`. That is the way you add a new icon theme for example.